# What do we mean by -Xdiags:verbos?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-calendar

While using Calendar class of java I am getting an error, the term **-Xdiags:verbos** is there in error message

Code:

```
public class CalendarClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE+ " / "+ Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR )); 
    }
    
}
```

Output:

CalendarClass.java:5: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE+ " / "+ Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR ));
^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with **-Xdiags:verbose** to get full output

So how I should resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is answered already. [Calendar.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) needs an `int` as parameter but your code delivers a `String` from the string concatenation `Calendar.DATE+ " / " + Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR`.

**To answer your question about the note**

`Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output`

It tells you that you could get a more verbose diagnostic mode while compiling when you add extra option `-Xdiags:verbose` to `javac`. In concrete example:

Without `-Xdiags:verbose`:

```
CalendarClass.java:N: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE+ " / " + Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR ));
                                                                                ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

The message points to the last `+` in string concatenation.

With `-Xdiags:verbose`:

```
CalendarClass.java:N: error: method get in class Calendar cannot be applied to given types;
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE+ " / " + Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR ));
                             ^
  required: int
  found:    String
  reason: argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int
1 error
```

The message points to the method `cal.get`.

For me the latter is more useful. That's why I always have that extra option set.

**How to set compiler options?**

That depends on how you are compiling. Using `javac` directly it is as simple as putting the compiler options in `javac` command line:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 -Xlint:deprecation -Xdiags:verbose -cp .;./depJars/* CalendarClass.java
```

Using an IDE please look at IDE's documentation on how to set extra options to `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new syntax for [`Calendar.get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) (it takes an `int`, not a `String`). Change

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE+ " / "
        + Calendar.MONTH + " / " + Calendar.YEAR ));
```

to

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) 
        + " / " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + " / "
        + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

But I would **strongly** suggest you replace all of that with the more modern `java.time` equivalent. Like,

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd / M / yyyy")
        .format(LocalDate.now()));
```

Both of which output (because today is January 30, 2022)

```
30 / 1 / 2022
```

Comment: Thanks I got that mistake. But what does that "-Xdiags:verbose " mean

Comment: **Some messages have been simplified**. Specifically, `String cannot be converted to int`. If you add that compiler directive your message will probably still be `String cannot be converted to int`. The compiler isn't sentient. You have an error and it's trying to be helpful.